# My xml file is not saving for hadoop in cloudera from root user

Tags: xml, hadoop, maven-2, cloudera, stanford-nlp

I am following this course in online http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs246/. For HW0, i faced an error.
HW0 > http://snap.stanford.edu/class/cs246-data-2014/hw0.pdf

HW0 told me to write a xml file in ~/.m2/settings.xml
I wrote the file from the pdf document and everything was okay except the file was not saving. 
i created the file using vim command. i edited the file and hit ESC and then :wq
Other files are closing after this command. So i tried it with root user. But the same error existed. 
here is the error: CAN'T open file for writing

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do so, you need to create a directory. Go in the console:

```
$ cd ~
$ sudo mkdir .m2/
```

Now you can create the settings.xml file via `vim`, update it and save it.

Comment: Were you able to create a project in Eclipse - I have issues with this directory as well? Any help appreciated (question posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795778/maven-project-in-eclipse-initial-setup)) Thanks!