# Maven Project in Eclipse - Initial Setup

Tags: eclipse, maven, cloudera

I am trying to follow some existing tutorials on Hadoop that I found online.
I have installed cloudera and am using it as the setup environment for all of the work. However when I try to create a Maven project in Eclipse, I end up having issues referencing to the quickstart archetype.
The error I get is the following:

> 'Creating maven-archetype-quickstart' has encountered a problem.
>
> Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:RELEASE from any of the configured repositories

The issue seems to be linked with the `~/.m2/` folder. My `settings.xml` file has been set up per the tutorial and links to the online repositories.

> Could not write artifact lastUpdated status /home/cloudera/.m2/repository/org/... (Permission denied)

Please note that I created the whole directory `.m2/` as it did ***not*** exist. I am running out of ideas, maven is clearly installed on the VM. I am just unsure why everything is referenced back to `~/.m2/` which did not exist and had to be created (and therefore isn't populated).

Whatever help would be appreciated, thanks again for your time!

Comment: Did you check the folder(s) read/write permissions of /home/cloudera/... ? Check https://maven.apache.org/settings.html for the default maven rep ({usr.home}/.m2) and how to specify your localRepository.

Comment: Thanks. I specified the local repository in the XML file. I will go ahead and confirm the r/w permissions however my concern is that the .m2 directory wasn't created and is empty right now besides the path I created for the repository. Is this normal?

Comment: when I was working m2 was in the home of the user account, not in the admin account. If you try to work from the root account of cloudera vm, you will not be able to write anything in the XML file.

Also, make sure You have written everything perfectly in the settings.xml inside the .m2 folder. 

Third, if you are working inside an university, then you might face problem downloading the contents from git and other repositories. In my case, most of the repos were closed through firewall from the IT and there was problem with proxy as well, so I have to dump the project lately. Thank you :)